Unable to remove Azure function even if the Function App is stopped
I have deployed an Azure Function App using a Basic 1 Service plan. At the Azure portal, I selected the available Blog trigger template with the BlobTrigger1 name. I would like to delete it, but both the Delete and the Disable options are disabled.

In the picture, you can see that the Function App is stopped, however I was not able to delete it.
How can I delete an Azure Function in Azure portal?

I have managed to find the solution. Go to the Functions > App files tab. Select the function app file (e.g. function_app.py) and remove the BlobTrigger1 function.
After refreshing the overview page, it shall disappear.

Note: You need to start the Function App to access the App files page.

